# How to click button that is showed after scrolling with firefox webdriver in Python?

Tags: javascript, python, html

Hi my problem is this: I need to scroll a page and at the end of scrolling appear a button, a classic "Show More" button, when i click this button i need to re-scroll the web-page 'till arrive to the end of the web-page.
What i've done 'till now is this:

```
from contextlib import closing

import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
from selenium.webdriver import Firefox # pip install selenium
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
url = 'https://play.google.com/store/apps/category/GAME_ARCADE/collection/topselling_free?hl=it'
# use firefox to get page with javascript generated content
SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME = 0.5

capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX
capabilities["marionette"] = True

# Get scroll height
with closing(Firefox(capabilities=capabilities)) as browser:
    browser.get(url)
    last_height = browser.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
    button = None
    while True:
        if (browser.find_element_by_id('show-more-button')):
            browser.find_element_by_id('show-more-button').click()
            #print("\n\nButton found = " + str(button) + "\n\n")

        # Scroll down to bottom
        browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")

        # Wait to load page
        time.sleep(SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME)

        # Calculate new scroll height and compare with last scroll height
        new_height = browser.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")

        if new_height == last_height:
            break
        last_height = new_height
    # wait for the page to load

    # store it to string variable
    page_source = browser.page_source
print(page_source)
```

What i want to do with this code is to check a button element in the page, if not exists yet, scroll the page. If the button element has been found, click it, and scroll the page again 'till the end.
The problem of this code is when i try to click the found button i receive this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/gfuccio/PycharmProjects/htmlParsing/generatedHtmlParser.py", line 21, in <module>
    browser.find_element_by_id('show-more-button').click()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 77, in click
    self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 493, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 252, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 194, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message:
```

I don't get why if the button is found, the click event doesn't work?
I hope that description of my problem is easy to understand.
Thanks in advance

**EDIT**
I've changed the if control in this way:

```
if (browser.find_element_by_id('show-more-button').is_displayed()):
    print("\n\n\nDisplayed!!\n\n\n")
```

But it results always false, although the generated html, after scrolling, contains the following element:

```
<button class="play-button" id="show-more-button" style="display:none">Mostra altro</button>
```

I know that the problem is the style attribute, but with javascript i think that this value is changed, don't you think? Because if i scroll the page 'till i find the button, whether i inspect the page i find the following situation:

[image: Page's inspection]

If you see the display attribute is setted to block. So why after scrolling i get the new html generated by javascript and the "style" attribute of the element is not changed?

Comment: The selenium docs explain what the error means: [Thrown when an element is present in the DOM but interactions with that element will hit another element due to paint order](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/common/selenium.common.exceptions.html#selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException) The button exists, but is hidden behind some other dom element, so you would be able to click it.